# How to validate object constraint in a object using joi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, object, joi

I am trying object validation with the help of joi.
I want to validate object as a constraint inside an object like

```
let login = {
    value: 0/1,
    slots: [{ label: '', value: '24 hr'}, { label: '', value: '24 hr'}]
}
```

Here `login` is an object and inside it `slots` is also an object. So if I write like the following

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
 value : Joi.number.required(),
 slots : Joi.string.required()
});
```

would it be correct for object data type or should I replace `string` data type with `object` data type?
I want to validate object type as a constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `slots` key needs to be an array of objects:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    value: Joi.number().required(),
    slots: Joi.array().items(
        Joi.object().keys({
            label: Joi.string().required().allow(''),
            value: Joi.string().required()
        })
    )
})
```

This way, the following object will be valid:

```
const obj = {
    value: 1,
    slots: [
        {
            label: '',
            value: '24 hr'
        }
    ]
}
```